# Can I configure Tailwind auto change by screen size?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

of cource i know, this code is fine.

```html
<p class="text-base lg:text-lg">FOOBAR</p>
```

But thi is a bit messy. I want to write just one class,

```html
<p class="text-base">FOOBAR</p>
```

and configure `tailwind.config.js` for auto change by the screen size. Likely, normal is `text-base` size, if `lg` is `text-lg` size.

Can I configured above option?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that is posible..

but you could use talwind's media queries and `@apply` to achieve it

```
.text-base {
   @apply text-sm;

   @screen lg {
     @apply text-lg;
   }
}
```

and use it like so

```
<p class="text-base">FOOBAR</p>
```

But note that this way you would be adding more styles, this approach even than it's less readable is more optimized:

```
<p class="text-sm lg:text-lg">FOOBAR</p>
```

Comment: thanks, i know media queries, and i think original code is readable too. but... It's a pain in the ass with so many components...:sweat: